# Can I upgrade my Turkish Airlines ticket to business class?

Tags: turkish-airlines, upgrades

I've purchased a ticket on Turkish Airlines from the US to Asia and would like to upgrade the transcontinental leg to business class. When I log into the Turkish Airlines website I'm only offered to upgrade the shorter leg for $450. Do I have to call Turkish Airlines to upgrade the longer leg? Or perhaps I can do it at check-in?

Comment: Is the longer leg operated by Turkish Airlines or by a partner? They may not be able to sell partner upgrades (or their website is too dumb). Or maybe there are no business seats at all, or no more remaining.

Comment: Normally they are all eager to sell you upgrades; but at check-in, they might be all gone.

Comment: @Aganju all Turkish airlines and there's still seats I can buy

Comment: Well, that leaves the dumb website option; and not all ticket classes are upgradable.